# Runing a program in gdb with an option

Tags: debugging, command-line, gdb

There is a program I usually run with -t as in `./program -t` but when I do `gdb ./program -t`, it says

```
gdb: option '-t' is ambiguous; possibilities: '-tui' '-tty'
Use `gdb --help' for a complete list of options.
```

I've tried `gdb --args ./program -t` as well but it doesn't work either (returns no such file or directory). Is there a way I could run this program in gdb with -t?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried `gdb --args ./program -t` as well

That is the correct way to invoke your program.

You could also do this:

```
gdb ./program
(gdb) run -t
```

> but it doesn't work either (returns no such file or directory)

This likely means that either `./program` doesn't exist, or is not runnable on your system. Or you could have something non-standard in your `~/.gdbinit` or in `./.gdbinit`.